# Rank & Rank.EQ function - Array reference error

Tags: excel, excel-formula, rank

<sub>**Background:**</sub>

Short question on the use of array references within `RANK` or `RANK.EQ` function.

Both function got the following parameters: `....(number,ref,[order])`

[Ms.Documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/rank-function-6a2fc49d-1831-4a03-9d8c-c279cf99f723) about the `Ref` parameter within `RANK` and `RANK.EQ`:

> "**Ref** Required. An array of, or a reference to, a list of numbers.
>   Nonnumeric values in ref are ignored."

Also, other websites I would normally highly recommend, would [state](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-rank-function) that the use of an array or list is possible within the `Ref` parameter.

---

<sub>**Sample data:**</sub>

```
| Rank1 | Rank2 | Overall |
|-------|-------|---------|
| 1     | 3     |         |
| 1     | 1     |         |
| 3     | 2     |         |
```

---

<sub>**Tried function:**</sub>

According to the documentation, the following in `C2` should work:

```
=RANK(A2+B2,INDEX(A$2:A$4+B$2:B$4,))
```

This evaluates to (using the build-in function):

```
=RANK(4,{4,2,5})
```

However returns, `#VALUE` error.

---

<sub>**Question:**</sub>

Can we state that only range references work as the `Ref` parameter and arrays simply don't work? Or am I missing some important piece of information here? Any canonical answer is welcome, I just want to make sure my hypothesis is correct.

For this specific case, to replicate the `RANK`, I would instead have to use something like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(($A$2:$A$4+$B$2:$B$4)<(A2+B2)))+1
```

Comment: Arrays don't work. They never have either, to the best of my recollection; the documentation is just wrong.

Comment: @Rory, Thanks, if this is the common understanding, please put this down as an answer. It doesn't need to be long, just wanted to get this cleared up and out of the way. Is there any reference to support this statement?

Comment: I can't really point you to a canonical reference to support that if MS' own  docs are wrong!

Comment: That's all good @Rory, just thought it could have been stated somewhere before since I don't think this is the first time someone hit this problem =)

Comment: I'm sure it's been stated in numerous forums over the years...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays don't work. They never have either, to the best of my recollection; the documentation is just wrong.