# How to Rank an array directly or a group of arrays without creating more cell references?

Tags: arrays, excel, rank

How to RANK an array directly? I would like to avoid creating more intermediate data in cells just to reference them.

Excel RANK.AVG formula states it accepts both array and reference:

```
Syntax
RANK.AVG(number,ref,[order])
The RANK.AVG function syntax has the following arguments:
Number  Required. The number whose rank you want to find.
Ref     Required. **An array of, or a reference to**, a list of numbers. Nonnumeric values in Ref are ignored.
Order   Optional. A number specifying how to rank number.
```

But Excel keeps rejecting the below formula.

```
=RANK.AVG(5, {3,1,7,10,5})
```

If the numbers are put in cells, say B1:B5, Excel accepts

```
=RANK.AVG(5, B1:B5}
```

Ultimately, I would like to rank a dynamic array

```
=RANK.AVG(value, TOCOL(VSTACK(array1, array2))

e.g. =RANK.AVG(5, TOCOL(VSTACK(B1:B5,C1:C10))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the official documentation on the various `RANK` functions is simply wrong with respect to the fact that they permit arrays for the *ref* argument (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59374601/rank-rank-eq-function-array-reference-error), for example).

You will have to come up with creative alternatives which mimic the `RANK.AVG` function, for example:

`=LET(ζ,SORT(MyArray,,-1),AVERAGE(FILTER(SEQUENCE(COUNT(ζ)),ζ=MyValue)))`

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I thought I was doing it wrong.

Comment: TIL about LET. I've been using LAMBDAs for this intermediate calculation. The answer could be extended to use a LAMBDA to have a "MYRANK" function for this purpose.